# C# .Trim not working for some reason

Tags: c#, .net

Alright, so basically, I'm trimming a string then making it lowercase. The lowercase part works perfectly well, but the sentence doesn't get trimmed. Any clue?

```
var result12 = TrimTheSentence("   John.   Doe@ gmaiL . cOm");
```

//the method is

```
    public static string TrimTheSentence(string givenString)
    {
        givenString = givenString.Trim();
        return givenString.ToLower();
```

Comment: What is the actual output, and what are you expecting?

Comment: the actual output is "john.   doe@ gmail . com) , I'm expecting the whitespaces gone

Comment: that is not how trim is supposed to work

Comment: Ah, so basically, what it does is it would remove the whitespaces from the front and the end of the string? As in, it combines TrimStart and TrimEnd?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is what you are looking for, you could shorten your method to just one line:

```
return givenString.Replace(" ", "").ToLower();
```

`Trim()` removes blank spaces from front and end of the string. It will not remove spaces that are ***in*** the string.

Examples:

```
"  Test String".Trim(); //Output: "Test String", it will remove only the leading spaces, but not the space between Test and String.
" Test String   ".Trim(); //Output: "Test String", it will remove leading and trailing spaces.
```

MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx

Comment: @X.L.Ant - Yeah, I noticed. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Aye, I'm using that as a placeholder, but the thing is - I'm trying to figure out why isn't trim working

Comment: @user2629770 -  `Trim()` removes blank spaces from front and end of the string. It will not remove spaces that are *in* the string.

Comment: @user2629770 - Glad to be of help. If the answer satisfies you, then upvote and mark it as answer.

Comment: Can't upvote any of the answers yet, unfortunately (I'm a new member)

Answer (score 12):

Trim removes spaces from the start/end, not from the entire string. Try:

```
return givenString.Replace(" ", "");
```

Comment: Aye, I'm using that as a placeholder, but the thing is - I'm trying to figure out why isn't trim working

Comment: @user2629770 - Because "Trim removes spaces from the start/end, not from the entire string". It's working [the way its supposed to work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a string extension method to remove white space within a string.

```
public static string RemoveWhiteSpaces(this string input)
{
    return Regex.Replace(input, @"\s+", "");
}
```